# Formula for how many combinations possible with 1 and 0 pattern and what branch

Tags: binary

How would one write the formula to calculate all possible combinations from a pattern with $4$ integers that are either $1$ or $0$.

Example of some possible patterns:

$0001,
~1010,
~0000,
~1111$

At first I was thinking $4 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 \cdot 4$ or $ 4^4 = 256.$ But I am not sure how to check.

Also what branch of mathematics would this fall under? (Example: Arithmetic, Algebra, etc.)

Comment: As an aside, the numbers can be interpreted as base2 numbers... the numbers being $0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,\dots,1110,1111$, or when interpreted away from binary into decimal as the numbers $0,1,2,3,4,5,\dots,15$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each position, you have $2$ options, hence in total, we have $2^4$ patterns.

Relevant topic: Combinatorics.